Updating a MKMapView based on transitions between UIViewControllers
I am building a map application similar to Apple Maps. Basically a half height sheet over a full screen map.
How shall I structure and detect transitions between view controllers on the sheet to update the map accordingly.
For example, let's say I have a Welcome VC and a Nearby Bus Stops VC. When the user goes from Welcome VC to Nearby Bus Stops VC, I want to add new bus stop annotations on the map. When the user go back to the Welcome VC from the Nearby Bus Stops VC, remove the annotations.
At the moment, I have a bunch of if-else statements which are not scalable as more view controllers are added and different possible combinations of transitions between view controllers are now possible in my app.
extension MainViewController: SheetControllerDelegate {
    func didChangeViewInSheet(from previousVC: UIViewController, to currentVC: UIViewController) {
        print("Changing from \(previousVC) to \(currentVC)")
        
        if currentVC is NearbyBusStopsVC && previousVC is WelcomeVC {
            addBusStopAnnotations()
        } else if previousVC is NearbyBusStopsVC && currentVC is WelcomeVC {

                removeBusStopAnnotations()

            //More code to run during this transition of view controllers in the sheet
        }
    }
}

Implementation of my SheetControllerDelegate
protocol SheetControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didChangeViewInWelcomeSheet(from previousVC: UIViewController, to currentVC: UIViewController)
}

class SheetController {
    static let shared = SheetController()
    
    weak var delegate: SheetControllerDelegate? = nil
    
    private var secondLastVC: UIViewController? = nil
    
    //The stack of view controllers currently held in the sheet. Only the top most view controller visible to user. Very similar to push and pop behaviour
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [] {
        willSet {
            secondLastVC = viewControllers.last
        }
        
        didSet {
            guard let topMostViewController = viewControllers.last else { return }
            guard let secondLastViewController = secondLastVC else { return }
            delegate?.didChangeViewInWelcomeSheet(from: secondLastViewController, to: topMostViewController)
        }
    }
    
    func present(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        
        guard let lastVC = viewControllers.last else { return }
        
        lastVC.present(viewController, animated: true)
        viewControllers.append(viewController)
    }
    
    func dismiss(_ onCompletion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        viewControllers.removeLast()
        guard let lastVC = viewControllers.last else { return }
        lastVC.dismiss(animated: true) {
            onCompletion?()
        }
    }
}


Your current code removes the annotations when NearbyBusStopsVC is presented. Did you mean the other way around? Also, why do you need to check both currentVC and previousVC in the same if? Why not just if currentVC is NearbyBusStopsVC { addBusStopAnnotations() } and if previousVC is NearbyBusStopsVC { removeBusStopAnnotations() }?

I can’t just check previous VC or current VC because there are different combinations of transitions in the app with their own respective functions to be executed.

So there are transitions from NearbyBusStopsVC where the bus stop annotations should not be removed?

I think you need to have the various view controllers add/remove their data in their willAppear/willDisappear methods.  Your map view shouldn't be concerned with determining which annotations to show, it should just be provided with annotations.
